# Track where files are installed during app installation in Linux

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I need to install some proprietary package from some vendor (i.e. nvidia, cisco, ...). I have some binary installation file which copy files to my filesystem during installation (to `/usr/share/`, `/etc/`, `/usr/bin/`, ...). But I don't know what and where exactly. When I want to install this APP there is not uninstall binary file and there could be problem with removing files of APP.

Is in Linux some tool(s) which can track where files are copied?

I would like to find some general solution without dependence on Linux distribution. My vision is something like `track ./install.bin` and output will be files which were manipulated.

On system I don't have tools like [locate](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-locate-command-practical-examples/).

Comment: Please let us know which Linux distribution you have so that we know which package manager you use.

Comment: Why not use `find`? With POSIX compliant options, you could use it in all distros

Comment: @Inian You are right and had the same idea as me, was typing the answer and did not see your comment.

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux but I would like to have some solution independent on Linux distribution.

Comment: For the record, this was also on Stack Overflow but is closed now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530061/how-to-track-in-linux-where-are-files-installed-during-installation-app

Comment: @waldauf `pacman` does not have a good interface for listing files changed from the installation package (like `rpm -qVa` or what was it in RPM-based systems) otherwise that would also have been an option. Go with `find`. If it is security critical, calculate hashes of all files (I can add that if you request it).

Comment: @Ned64: Many thx for your help and offer but I know how to calculate hashes `find / ... -exec mdsum '{}' + > /root/file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way: `find`.

The easiest method (easiest meaning, no extra tools to install, easy to type in) would be to save a list of all files before and after the install, then compare the lists.

You could type

```
find / -xdev \( -name home -o -name mnt -o -name proc --o -name dev o -name sys \) -prune -o -print | sort > /root/files-before-install
```

Then install your program and

```
find / -xdev \( -name home -o -name mnt -o -name proc -o -name dev -o -name sys \) -prune -o -print | sort > /root/files-after-install
```

(please note the other file name at the end)

Afterwards you can compare the files like this:

```
diff /root/files-before-install /root/files-after-install
```

This will show you only new files, not changed files - this would be much more complex to detect. There is also a non-zero chance that your installation program will create a file or directory with the name "home", "mnt", "sys", "proc" or "dev" which we would ignore, but the chances for this are pretty low in my opinion.

Comment: I hoped for some "finished tool" but your solution is general and useful on all distributions. Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Checkinstall](https://checkinstall.izto.org/) works exactly like you describe: it monitors file system changes performed by an installer process, and provides a way to roll them all back.

There are ways to turn the installation transcript into a regular package for a number of platforms (`.deb`, RPM, etc) but the tool is useful even if you don't want that, or your package manager isn't directly supported.